# getting error when using play/ stop button

Tags: android, button, android-mediaplayer

I have **10 buttons for playing 10 songs**. i want to achieve when i press the same button while playing, it should be stop . when i press the another button it should be stop the previous song and play the new song ..
but i couldn't achieve both things using same code 
i have tried it 
when i use this code ,**the stop won't  work for same button**,  but it worked for another  playing new song .

```
  private void playSample(int[] res, int position)
  {

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(res[position]);
    try
    {   if(mp.isPlaying())
    {
        mp.stop();
    }
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        afd.close();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
 }
```

so i have tried like this

```
   private void playSample(int[] res, int position)
   {

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(res[position]);

    try
    {   if(mp.isPlaying())
    {
        mp.stop();
    }else
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        afd.close();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

now   the stop will work for same button  .but when i press another button while playing .it wont start the new song

Comment: What exactly is the problem: 1) Find out which song is playing currently or 2) Pause the currently playing song?

Comment: **now the play/pause will working gud .but when i press the button while playing .it wont start.it stops the previous songs..** sorry but did not get this ?

Comment: @NetStarter when i press the another button while playing .it should stop the current song and play the new song for that button.but it stop the current song.not playing new song...

Comment: @MichaelButscher now read the question ,you will get it..

Comment: ok then you should try by saving state of the button pressed as 1)string sngStatus = "SongPlaying" 2) sngStatus = "SongPaused" 3) sngStatus = "sngStopped" and chck corresponding action as if(mp.isPlaying() && snsStatus.equals("SongPlaying") ) something like this

Comment: @NetStarter i don't want to pause the songs ,because the  file is small ,but i will try ...

Comment: ok then try for other events play and stop.hope it helps you to solve your problem also what does this **getting error when using play/ stop button** suggest which error you are getting ?

Comment: @DivyaRamakrishnan As ramin eftekhari already pointed out your second variant is wrong and the first variant is only right if another button was pressed. So first of all you must be able to decide if `playSample()` was called for the same song currently playing or not. Or is this detected somewhere else?

Comment: @NetStarter error (-38,0)

Answer (score 0):

check if media playing just stop it and play requested media.no need to `else`.

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.stop();
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
afd.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is calling start without waiting for onPrepared listener. Error (-38,0) is invalid operation, so which mostly probably be calling start when it was not even finished preparing.